# shell awk print in range

Tags: bash, shell, awk

my txt file is constructed like:

```
random text
random text
random text

start_here
important text
important text
important text
end_here

random text
random text

start_here
important text
important text
important text
end_here

...
start_here
...
end_here
...
```

i need to print everything between start_here and end_here (no matter if these lines are in or not) in a new file.

**i tried with awk but the output file is empty.**

```
awk '/start_here/,/end_here/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It works for me. Do you have output without `> outputfile.txt`

Comment: also no output without "> outputfile.txt"

Comment: Do you get output if you do `awk '1' inputfile.txt` ?

Comment: i found a solution. i needed to change the path of the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me, but you can try:

```
awk '/start_here/{f=1} f; /end_here/{f=0}' file
```

or

```
awk '/start_here/{f=1} /end_here/{f=0;print} f' file
```

All gives this:

```
start_here
important text
important text
important text
end_here
start_here
important text
important text
important text
end_here
start_here
...
end_here
```

If you do not like the start/end text use this:

```
awk '/end_here/{f=0} f; /start_here/{f=1}' file

important text
important text
important text
important text
important text
important text
...
```

Comment: thank you for all the ideas. i have no error appearing. its "just" the output which is missing.

Comment: Run it with out any `> output` so you see what is going on.  Try also `awk '{print $0} file` just to see if `file` is read, and you get any output.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work
I have tested [here](http://ideone.com/g1EyH2)

you can also use  perl:

```
perl -lne 'print if(/start_here/.../end_here/)'
```

Tested [here](http://ideone.com/oSKvEd)

Answer (score 0):

Your script is almost a working `sed` script:

```
sed -n '/start_here/,/end_here/p' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```